# sending an email through sharepoint REST api in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I have been trying to send an email to the sharepoint user on click of a button in a client side web page.

I am trying to use the REST API using JSOM
and the code looks like below.

```
sendEmail("user@domain.com", "rec@domain.com", "test", "test-email");
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            'From': from,
            'To': { 'results': [to] },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }
  ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
       alert("Eposten ble sendt");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err.responseText);
        debugger;
    }
});
}
```

The issue what am facing here is:
1. Am getting an error 404 Not Found => does it mean my server does not have the utilities api?
2. When i tried (siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail") in browser it gives 404 not found.

Let me know how to resolve this issue.(Note: i dont have access to central admin).
(or)
Is there any other way to send an email without using workflow? or to call an workflow from a script?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to send E-Mail through Rest API in SharePoint.

Code get from this [Link](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/11/send-email-through-rest-api-in-sharepoint/)

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlEmail,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
          'properties': {
          '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
          'Body': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
          'To' : { 'results': ['admin@codeplayandlearn.com'] },
          'Subject': "E-Mail From REST API";
       }
    }),
    headers: {
       "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
       "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
       "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
       alert("Email Send Successful.");
    },
    error: function (err) {
       alert(err.responseText);
    }
});
```